# MSBuild error 1 has ended this build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-definition

I am trying to integrate Gulp in TFS builds and web deploy using the article given [here](http://www.codecadwallader.com/2015/03/15/integrating-gulp-into-your-tfs-builds-and-web-deploy/#comment-1119) as reference. When I build the solution using the command (Alt+B+R), an output directory gets successfully created by gulp. But, when I try to queue a new build by right-clicking my build definition, the build fails with the following error.

Can anyone help to get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs under "Log" tab?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error *TF42097: A work item could not be saved due to  a filed error.*

The build uses the Default Template (or a customization) and has the Create Work Item on Failure option turned on, however the Bug work item has been modified in a way that means the build is unable to create it – which could be as simple as making a field mandatory.

How you fix this depends on how the Bug work item has been restricted. Work item fields that have been made mandatory should have a value specified in the build process template, and if that value should vary depending on the build definition you will need to expose it as an argument in the definition.

A workaround for this situation:

Adding in a PropertyGroup `<SkipWorkItemCreation>true</SkipWorkItemCreation>` will stop it from attempting to create the work item.

A similar question from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e278257b-bf6a-4512-a1c4-085e58cbd286/tf42097-a-work-item-could-not-be-created-due-to-a-field-error?forum=tfsbuild) for you reference.